# Linear independence in relation to a set

Tags: linear-algebra

We have a Vector $V$ on  $\mathbb R^2$.  The set $E=\{u,v,w\}$ has linear independence.
Evaluate if the following are independent as well;

$A = \{u + v, 2v + w, u + w\}$ and

$B =\{u, u + v, u + v + w\}$

I do not hava a clue of what is questioning. Some guidance will be great.

Comment: The first sentence makes no sense here, but the rest is asking whether, given that vectors $u, v, w$ are linearly independent, $u+v, 2v+w, u+w$ are also linearly independent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming that $V$ is a real vector space and that $E=\{u,v,w\}$ is a linearly independent set in $V$. To determine if $A=\{u+v,2v+w,u+w\}$ is linearly independent, suppose that
$$
\lambda_1\cdot(u+v)+\lambda_2\cdot(2v+w)+\lambda_3\cdot(u+w)=\mathbf0\tag{1}
$$
Note that (1) is equivalent to
$$
(\lambda_1+\lambda_3)\cdot u+(\lambda_1+2\lambda_2)\cdot v+(\lambda_2+\lambda_3)\cdot w=\mathbf 0\tag{2}
$$
Since $E$ is independent, (2) is satisfied if and only if 
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0 & 1 \\
1 & 2 & 0 \\
0 & 1 & 1
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
\lambda_1\\ \lambda_2\\ \lambda_3
\end{bmatrix}
=
\begin{bmatrix}
0\\ 0\\0
\end{bmatrix}\tag{3}
$$
Now, observe that
$$
\det
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0 & 1 \\
1 & 2 & 0 \\
0 & 1 & 1
\end{bmatrix}=3
$$
(check this yourself!) so (3) has only the solution
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
\lambda_1\\ \lambda_2\\ \lambda_3
\end{bmatrix}
=
\begin{bmatrix}
0\\ 0\\0
\end{bmatrix}
$$
Hence (1) has only the trivial solution $\lambda_1=\lambda_2=\lambda_3=0$ and $A$ is independent.

Can you construct a similar argument for $B$?

Answer (score 0):

Consider $c_1(u+v)+c_2(2v+w)+c_3(u+w)=0$

$\Rightarrow u(c_1+c_3)+v(c_1+2c_2)+w(c_2+c_3)=0$

Now as $E$ is linearly independent then we have $(c_1+c_3)=(c_1+2c_2)=(c_2+c_3)=0\Rightarrow c_1=c_2=c_3=0\Rightarrow$ $A$ is linearly independent

Similar procedure can be followed for $B$ also to obtain that $B$ is also linearly independent.