# Linearly independent vectors problem

Tags: linear-algebra

I want to solve this problem:

Assume $A=\{u,v,w\}$ is a linearly independent set of vectors. Determine if set of vectors $B=\{u-2v+w, u+v, u-v\}$ is linearly independent.

So my logic tells me that since the problem doesn't give more information about vectors, it must be a rule of thumb whether a set with operations with linearly independent vectors is linearly independent as well. Am I missing something? What linear algebra property applies to my problem?

Comment: what do you mean by $wu$ or $v(u-v)$? They are not even vectors. Moreover your $B$ is NOT a set.

Comment: The problem actually defined $B$ this way: $B={u-2v+w,u+v,u-v}$ I assumed the commas were just multiplications. Not sure if that makes $wu$ and $v(u-v)$ vectors

Comment: commas are not sign for multiplication. They are denoting different elements of the set. I am editing your problem.

Comment: check this http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/824085/linear-independence-in-relation-to-a-set . It would be helpful for you to understand the notation better.

Answer (score 0):

We try to find real numbers $a,b,c$ with $$a(u-2v+w)+b(u+v)+c(u-v)=0$$

for a triple $(a,b,c)\ne (0,0,0)$

We get $$(a+b+c)u+v(-2a+b-c)+aw=0$$

Since $u,v,w$ are linear independent, we can conclude $a+b+c=-2a+b-c=a=0$

This gives $b+c=b-c=0$ If we add the equations $b+c=0$ and $b-c=0$ we get $2b=0$ implyig $b=0$ and finally we get $c=0$. Hence, the given set of vectors is linear independent.

Comment: May I ask what method did you use to you go from $a(u−2v+w)+b(u+v)+c(u−v)=0$ to $(a+b+c)u+v(−2a+b−c)+aw=0$ ?

Comment: Multiplying out , you get $au-2av+aw+bu+bv+cu-cv$. Rearrange the terms to get $au+bu+cu-2av+bv-cv+aw$